# Shiny R inputFile as FileChooser

Tags: r, file, upload, shiny

NOTE: This application is not meant to be deployed in a remote server, just in a local machine. I use Shiny because it's easy to create a friendly user interface.

In my application I need to select a file from a local machine. The only means I found for this were `file.choose()` and `fileInput()`. The first option does the work but it isn't user friendly because the file chooser won't appear on top of the browser... Not even as a new element in the task bar, so the user could be confused.

1) Is there another way to do this? (Not using fileInput as fileChooser)

2) If not, is there a way to hide the uploading bar?  It doesn't make any sense for a fileChooser.

[image]

I don't know what to modify here in order to hide the upload bar.

EDIT: I also use other progress bars in my application, so I'm not sure if hiding the progress-bar class would hide all my `progress <- shiny::Progress$new()`

[image]

Comment: Shiny is a client-server application, so even if you are running it locally, there is still a client (your browser) and a server (started by RStudio/shiny). Shiny needs to **upload** and send the file to the server, so that is why the progress bar makes sense. As your screenshot shows, you can probably explicitly hide the div class `shiny-file-input-progress` which would then not influence other progress bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment by warmoverflow, this is all that's needed.

```
tags$style(type="text/css", ".shiny-file-input-progress { display: none }")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an R package [shinyFiles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFiles/). It's description:

> Provides functionality for client-side navigation of the server side
>   file system in shiny apps. In case the app is running locally this
>   gives the user direct access to the file system without the need to
>   "download" files to a temporary location. Both file and folder
>   selection as well as file saving is available.